# Adobe Catalyst: rounded corners

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, flashcatalyst

I've created a rectangle in catalyst and under the "properties" panel, all I can see is `Corners 10` for the rectangle. Is there a way to individually define each corner similar to CSS. I can't see any source code view in catalyst to enable me to fine tune it for each of the 4 corners. How do I specify the roundedness of each corner separately?

Answer (score 0):

I think its no way you can do it in Catalyst, but after importing project into the Flex, you could adjust each corner manually by editing the CSS file.